# Initializing a box with N particles arranged in a specific pattern

Tags: c++, montecarlo

I'm new to C++, and as an exercise I'm trying to reproduce what was done by Metropolis et al. (Metropolis Monte Carlo).

**What I have done thus far - Made 2 classes: Vector and Atom**

```
class Vector {
public:
    double x;
    double y;
    Vector() {

    }
    Vector (double x_, double y_) {
        x = x_;
        y = y_;
    }
    double len() {
        return sqrt(x*x + y*y);
    }
    double lenSqr() {
        return x*x + y*y;
    }
};

class Atom {
public:
    Vector pos;
    Vector vel;
    Vector force;
    Atom (double x_, double y_) {
        pos = Vector(x_, y_);
        vel = Vector(0, 0);
        force = Vector(0, 0);
    }
    double KE() {
        return .5 * vel.lenSqr();
    }
 };
```

I am not certain that the way I have defined the class Atom is... the best way to go about things since I will not be using a random number generator to place the atoms in the box.

**My problem:**
I need to initialize a box of length L (in my case L=1) and load it with 224 atoms/particles in an offset lattice (I have included a picture). I have done some reading and I was wondering if maybe an array would be appropriate here.

One thing that I am confused about is how I could normalize the array to get the appropriate distance between the particles and what would happen to the array once the particles begin to move. I am also not sure how an array could give me the x and y position of each and every atom in the box.

[Metropolis offset (hexagonal) lattice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtdYe.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Daniel - I hope my edited question is a little more clear.

Comment: Do you mean cube by `box of length L`? Is it 3-dimensional entity?

Comment: @MrPisarik - It's a 2D box, I hastily copied some code over and forgot to delete the z components! I've changed it now to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems, that generally you **don't need to use array to represent the lattice**. In practice most often it may sense to represent lattice as array only if your *atoms* can naturally move only on the cells (for example as figures in chess). But seems that your atoms can move in any direction (already not practicle to use such rigid structure as array, because it has naturally 4 or 8 directions for move in 2D) by any step (it is bad for arrays too, because in this case you need almost countless cells in array to represent minimal distance step).

So basically what do you need is just use array as storage for your 224 atoms and set particular position in lattice via pos parameter.

```
std::vector<Atom> atoms;

// initialize atoms to be in trigonal lattice
const double x_shift  = 1. / 14;
const double y_shift  = 1. / 16;

double x_offset = 0;
for (double y = 0; y < 1; y += y_shift){
    for (double x = x_offset; x < 1; x += x_shift){
        // create atom in position (x, y)
        // and store it in array of atoms
        atoms.push_back(Atom(x, y));
    }
    // every new row flip offset 0 -> 1/28 -> 0 -> 1/28...
    if (x_offset == 0){
        x_offset = x_shift / 2;
    }
    else{
        x_offset = 0;
    }
}
```

Afterwards you just need to process this array of atoms and change their positions, velocities and what you need else according to algorithm.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a shot.